# jQuery - How to find a class outside the parent div and click on a child class of another parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm using jQuery to close the navigation in responsive view by triggering `$(".navbar-toggle").click()`. However I can't find a way to close the nav on click of drop down links and on click of the logo.

As this web app has been developed in **Meteor** the pages do not reload hence the navigation remains expanded.

The Problem:

1. How to collapse the navigation on click of dropdown links?
2. How to collapse the navigation on click of the logo if navigation is opened?
3. How to collapse the navigation on click of the right nav dropdown links?

as `.navbar-toggle` is outside their respective parent divs I am not able to target them.

Below is my code :

```js
$('.nav-link').on('click', function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 990){
     $('.navbar-toggle').click()
  };
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand nav-link" href="#">
        LOGO
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Community <span class="ti-angle-down"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"><a href="#" class="nav-link-outside">Teams</a>
            </li>
            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"><a href="#" class="nav-link-outside">Events</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse" class="nav-link"><a href="#">Events</a>
        </li>


      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">User name <span class="ti-angle-down"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Profile settings</a>
            </li>
            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Change password</a>
            </li>
            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"><a href="#" id="signout" class="nav-link">Sign out</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-->
</nav>
```

Comment: I think all your problem points are working fine. Just checkd your snippet

Answer (score 0):

All your points are working, Except one was partially working.  That is the point 3. `How to collapse the navigation on click of the right nav dropdown links?`

It was partially working because the links under the section `community` has the class `nav-link-outside` and not `nav-link`. So use the below selector in your jquery.

```js
$('.nav-link,.nav-link-outside').on('click', function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 990){
     $('.navbar-toggle').click()
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand nav-link" href="#">
        LOGO
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Community <span class="ti-angle-down"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"><a href="#" class="nav-link-outside">Teams</a>
            </li>
            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"><a href="#" class="nav-link-outside">Events</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse" class="nav-link"><a href="#">Events</a>
        </li>


      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">User name <span class="ti-angle-down"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Profile settings</a>
            </li>
            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Change password</a>
            </li>
            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"><a href="#" id="signout" class="nav-link">Sign out</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-->
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Reddy! despite that error it doesn't work on my web app. This is the link to my staging site http://gushou.deepertest.com/

Comment: @JoystanFernandes Have you loaded the scripts to handle the toggle in the link you provided?? I tried just pasting my above given script in console window of your site and it started working fine.